# New Magento 2.4.3-p1 instance - language switcher not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1, language-switcher

I have a problem.

I have a shop in 5 languages.

`English`-`German`-`Spanish`-`French`-`Italian`

All stores set up fine with store codes

English - en
German - de
Spanish - es
French - fr
Italian - it

Under `Configuration --> General --> Web --> Add Store Code to Urls = YES`
CMS Home Page per Store View all set

URLs work normally when I add the language codes to the URL `XYZ.com/en`, `XYZ.com/de`, etc.

Subpages also work fine, when I manually add the Store Code

**My problem:**

**When using the language switcher it only directs me to the English and the German store page.**

**Strange is also that when I am in the English store `XYZ.com/en` and mouse over the other languages in the language switcher, it shows me `XYZ.com/en/#` as it does when I am in the german store it shows me `XYZ.com/de/#` when I hover over the languages.**

Does anyone have an idea how or where to fix this?

Best regards

Comment: There is some issue with store language store website configuration from admin side.

Comment: Please check: https://magefan.com/blog/configure-magento-2-multi-language-store

Comment: my idea, check if translate code have a url link from language to another language in each reference in translate file, see if is not empty.  if scripts okay, check too url regex conditionals from your web server. In last case use a translate module  from Magento Plugin Store. See more in:  https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=switch%20language

Comment: might be a stupid idea but try setting the link urls too in admin, sth like xyz.com/en ?

Comment: Having a similar issue, are you using varnish cache? Could be that the store cookies are not set right… Still having the issue wil post my solution if it’s fixed

Comment: Hi @Center, not using varnish cash. It seems that while importing stores and store codes from another instance the store codes got mixed up in the database.